# Can I send event to knative broker directly?

Tags: knative, knative-eventing

I have installed kubernetes v1.23 and knative v1.4 on a cluster with three machines. I read from knative [doc](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/brokers/) that event producers can send events to a broker by POSTing the event. So I write a demo to send events to broker using the [cloudevents sdk-go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/v2). But I get 404 when the code sends cloudevents. I'm not sure if sending to broker directly is not allowd in knative v1.4 or I take wrong approch. Can anyone help me?

Here is the step I take. I want to see event being sent without error.

1. Get the ip of service broker-ingress behind knative broker.

```
kubectl get svc -n knative-eventing
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                     AGE
broker-filter             ClusterIP   10.108.220.37    <none>        80/TCP,9092/TCP             46h
broker-ingress            ClusterIP   10.107.184.78    <none>        80/TCP,9092/TCP             46h
eventing-webhook          ClusterIP   10.109.176.134   <none>        443/TCP                     46h
imc-dispatcher            ClusterIP   10.107.114.179   <none>        80/TCP,9090/TCP             46h
inmemorychannel-webhook   ClusterIP   10.100.49.85     <none>        443/TCP,9090/TCP,8008/TCP   46h
```

2. Write a demo to send events.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    cloudevents "github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/v2"
    "github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/v2/client"
)

var ceClient client.Client

type TempEvent struct {
    Celsius int32 `json:"celsius,int32"`
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Client started")

    // ip and port of broker-ingress
    sink := "http://10.107.184.78:80"
    var err error
    ceProtocol, err := cloudevents.NewHTTP(cloudevents.WithTarget(sink))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create CloudEvent protocol: %s", err)
    }   
    ceClient, err = cloudevents.NewClient(ceProtocol, cloudevents.WithUUIDs(), cloudevents.WithTimeNow())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create CloudEvent client: %s", err)
    }

    // construct event
    provider := "aws"
    zone := "us-east"
    machine := "monet"

    event := cloudevents.NewEvent("1.0")
    event.SetType("temp")
    event.SetSource(fmt.Sprintf(
        "//node/%s/%s/%s", provider, zone, machine,
    ))
    event.SetExtension("provider",
        fmt.Sprintf("//provider/%s", provider))
    event.SetExtension("providerZone",
        fmt.Sprintf("//provider-zone/%s/%s", provider, zone))

    if err := event.SetData(cloudevents.ApplicationJSON, TempEvent{Celsius: 80}); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to set CloudEvents data: %s", err)
    }

    // send event
    ctx := cloudevents.ContextWithTarget(context.Background(), "http://10.107.184.78:80")
    if res := ceClient.Send(ctx, event); !cloudevents.IsACK(res) {
        log.Printf("Failed to send CloudEvent: %+v", res)
    }
}
```

3. Run the code and get error.

```
go run main.go
2023/05/31 19:41:01 Client started
2023/05/31 19:41:01 Failed to send CloudEvent: 404:
```

Comment: from you are running the code inside same namespace or local PC while other app running running on minikube what's your setup?

Comment: @Manvar The demo code is a process running on the master node of kubernetes cluster. And my kubernetes environment is installed by kubectl not minikube.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your target/sink URL is not correct.

The `broker-ingress` service is the entrypoint for multiple logical brokers (the ones you can create for example via `kn broker create`) and thus requires additional information (namespace & broker name) in the path to route the request to the correct logical broker instance:

```
http://broker-ingress.knative-eventing.svc.cluster.local/<namespace>/<broker name>
```

You can get this URL from the broker object itself too:

```
$ kubectl get broker                                                                        
NAME        URL                                                                          AGE   READY   REASON
my-broker   http://broker-ingress.knative-eventing.svc.cluster.local/default/my-broker   10d   True
```